# Django format database entry in template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to show office hours for a doctor and would like to have the hours for the same day in one line, instead of having them on different lines.

For instance, this is how it's currently showed in the templates

```
Sunday: 9 am - noon
Sunday: 1pm - 9pm
Monday: 8:30am - 11am
```

I want it to be shown

```
Sunday: 9am - noon , 1pm - 9pm
Monday: 8:30am - 11am
```

How can I do that?

## models.py

```
WEEKDAYS = [
  (1, ("Sunday")),
  (2, ("Monday")),
  (3, ("Tuesday")),
  (4, ("Wednesday")),
  (5, ("Thursday")),
  (6, ("Friday")),
  (7, ("Saturday")),
]


class OpeningHour(models.Model):

    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    weekday = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS)
    from_hour = models.TimeField(unique=False)
    to_hour = models.TimeField(unique=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('weekday', 'from_hour')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s: %s: %s - %s' % (self.doctor.name, self.get_weekday_display(),
                                 self.from_hour, self.to_hour)
```

## template.py

```
 {% for a in Hours %}
                <p>{{a.get_weekday_display}}: {{a.from_hour}} - {{a.to_hour}}</p>
            {% endfor %}
```

## hours list

[image]

## views.py

```
hours = OpeningHour.objects.filter(doctor_id=id)
```

Comment: Please, show your `Hours` list.

Comment: not sure what do you mean by that?

Comment: From `{% for a in Hours %}`, can you show `Hours` list?. I ask because I think you need [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot from the database. In the views I'm just filtering it   hours = OpeningHour.objects.filter(doctor_id=id)

Comment: Consider also reusing an existing [Django app](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/calendar/) with similar features.

Comment: I mean the list you get in your view and send to your template.

Comment: I suppose you have 2 OpeningHour instances for the same doctor and weekday: one for the morning, other one for the afternoon. Maybe you could change your model to have from_hour_AM, to_hour_AM, from_hour_PM and to_hour_PM. Then you will have a single OpeningHour instance for a doctor and a weekday.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `hours` in the template represent an ordered list of OpeningHour objects (ordered by weekday), then you can use the [ifchanged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag. Something like:

```
{% for a in hours %}
    {% ifchanged a.weekday %}
        <p> {{a.get_weekday_display}}:
    {% endifchanged %}
    {{a.from_hour}} - {{a.to_hour}}, 
    {% ifchanged a.weekday %}
        </p>
    {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

(should probably be adapted to take into account some limit conditions, but this is the idea)